# How to install codecs for opencv?

Tags: c++, opencv, ffmpeg

I am trying to write a program that captures video from a webcam using this code:

```
#include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>
#include <iostream>

using namespace cv;
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{

    Mat frame;
    VideoCapture cap(1);
    char key;
    String outputName = "output.avi";

    VideoWriter outputVideo;
    Size size = Size(cap.get(CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH), cap.get(CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT));



    outputVideo.open(outputName, CV_FOURCC('D', 'I', 'V', 'X'), cap.get(CV_CAP_PROP_FPS), size, true);

    if (!outputVideo.isOpened())
    {
        cout << "Could not open the output video for write: " << outputName << endl;
        return -1;
    }
    cout << "size " << size.width << " x " << size.height << endl;

    namedWindow("Display window", WINDOW_AUTOSIZE); // Create a window for display.
    cap.set(CV_CAP_PROP_EXPOSURE, -8);


    while (true){
        bool success = cap.read(frame);
        if (!success){
            cout << "Cannot read frame from file" << endl;
            return -2;
        }
        outputVideo.write(frame);
        imshow("Display window", frame);
        key = waitKey(1);
        if (key == ' '){
            cout << "Video ended due to key stroke" << endl;
            return 1;
        }
    }


    return 0;
}
```

The program doesn't seem to be able to open outputVideo since it always returns -1. I thought that I might not have the codec divx installed, but I have installed it from k-lite codec pack and divx and it still does not work.

Could anybody please tell me how to install codecs **such that opencv recognizes them**?

I am using OpenCV 2.4.10 on Windows 7 with Visual studio 2013.

Comment: Have you tried this with a static path name, because -1 in your code means its not opening the file, not decoding it. (Don't forget to use \\)

Comment: It is opening the file. That is not the problem. I have tried inserting -1 at the codec argument when creating the videoWriter and it showed me 3 codecs nobody heard from and which were terrible. The file was opened and videos were created. The issue is that I am getting the error when I am trying to use a normal codec like divx, xvid or h264 it stops working.